# How to truncate python datetime(ISO) to hour?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to truncate the following datetime stamps at hour. I couldn't find a good solution to do this in Python with Pandas.

The original data look like:

```
0   2013-01-01 05:39:00
1   2013-01-01 09:04:00
2   2013-01-01 13:16:00
3   2013-01-01 13:14:00
4   2013-01-01 14:51:00
Name: entry_time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I may need it to be:

```
0   2013-01-01 05:00:00
1   2013-01-01 09:00:00
2   2013-01-01 13:00:00
3   2013-01-01 13:00:00
4   2013-01-01 14:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert column to `numpy.ndarray` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) and convert it by [`numpy.ndarray.astype`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html):

```
df['entry_time'] = df['entry_time'].values.astype('<M8[h]')
print df
           entry_time
0 2013-01-01 05:00:00
1 2013-01-01 09:00:00
2 2013-01-01 13:00:00
3 2013-01-01 13:00:00
4 2013-01-01 14:00:00
```

Or you can [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) `replace` *minutes* and *seconds* to `0`:

```
df['entry_time'] = df['entry_time'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(minute=0, second=0))
print df
           entry_time
0 2013-01-01 05:00:00
1 2013-01-01 09:00:00
2 2013-01-01 13:00:00
3 2013-01-01 13:00:00
4 2013-01-01 14:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! I did it with your first solution!

Answer (score 0):

A possible choice is to make every string into a `datetime` [object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) and use `strftime` to get the desired output

```
return dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%w %H:00:00')
```

[docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)